# Split transpose not considering first character as separator - any alternative?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this table:

[image]

In each of the cells there is a long list separated by ",":

```
Rosângela Lima, Ana Carolina Chagas, Sergio Vasquez, Rosana Corrêa, Michele Kida
Analista De Treinamento E …, A procura de nova oportunidade no mercado, Comercial na BRASILMAXI Logística Ltda., Executiva de Vendas e Solucionadora do Grupo BRASILMAXI, Executiva de Vendas na Brasilmaxi Logística LTDA
, achagas@brasilmaxi.com.br, sergio.vasquez@brasilmaxi.com.br, rosana.correa@brasilmaxi.com.br, ,
@ros%C3%A2ngela-lima-4a90a324, @ana-carolina-chagas-24997022, @sergio-vasquez-25a040a4, @rosanacorrea, @michele-kida-83929230
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

[Here is the sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e79z_WtyFp9MbNa0ARrGhWxvfIF_Ow3Sf44JCu4j6xc/edit#gid=0)

I tried to use `transpose(split())` however it doesn't work the email line properly:

[image]

Google Sheets is not considering the first character as separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "MY TRY" of your shared Spreadsheet, how about modifying the formula at "C15" as follows?

#### From:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C3;","))
```

#### To:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C3;",";;FALSE))
```

- About 4th argument, the official document says as follows.

  > remove_empty_text  - [ OPTIONAL - TRUE by default ] - Whether or not to remove empty text messages from the split results. The default behavior is to treat consecutive delimiters as one (if TRUE). If FALSE, empty cells values are added between consecutive delimiters.

#### Reference:

- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

### Added:

In order to retrieve the front space of each row, how about the following modified formulas?

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(C3;" ";"");",";;FALSE))
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(C3;",";;FALSE))))
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, it is a great suggestion. However it keeps adding a blank space in the start of the line. When I throw this into other tools, that space is going to give me a big headache. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @abutremutante Thank you for replying. About the front space of each row, I added 2 more formulas in my answer. Could you please confirm it?